# How can I fix the bug in ACADO Toolkit when using OnlineData variables?

Tags: c++, optimization

As exposed in [this topic](https://sourceforge.net/p/acado/discussion/general/thread/b0225791/#8c56) in ACADO forum, there is a bug when you try to use OnlineData variables. In my case I am using C++ code instead of MATLAB interface and have 7 OnlineData variables. In the topic mentioned before they propose using the function SetNOD but using C++ I can't call the function. I cannot access the official forum in sourcefourge because they have some problems and I would appreciate your help.

The abbreviated code is:

## include

## define N  20 //Time intervals -- 51 states

```
int main{

USING_NAMESPACE_ACADO

    //Variables
        DifferentialState   x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, roll, pitch, yaw, droll, dpitch, dyaw;
        Control     u1, u2, u3, u4;
        OnlineData   yaw0, obsx, obsy, obsz, obsrx, obsry, obsrz; 
       . . .

    //Create Optimal Control Problem object
        OCP ocp(t_start, t_end, N); //50 number of discretization intervals

    //Fixing the bug
        //Alternatives I tried
        ocp.SetNOD(7);//Error A
        //ocp.ModelContainer.SetNOD(7);//Error B


    //Objective Function        
        ocp.minimizeLSQ(Q, h);
        ocp.minimizeLSQEndTerm(QN, hN);

    /* Constraints */
        //Model constraint
            ocp.setModel( f );

    /* Export OCP */

    OCPexport mpc( ocp );
    ... 

    if (mpc.exportCode( "path_qp_export_oases" ) != SUCCESSFUL_RETURN)
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

return 0;
```

}

Error A:

/.../path_qp_generated_oases.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/.../path_qp_generated_oases.cpp:321:9: error: ‘class ACADO::OCP’ has no member named ‘SetNOD’
     ocp.SetNOD(7);

make[2]: [.../CMakeFiles/my_examples_path_qp_generated_oases.dir/my_examples/path_qp_generated_oases.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1](https://sourceforge.net/p/acado/discussion/general/thread/b0225791/#8c56): .../CMakeFiles/my_examples_path_qp_generated_oases.dir/all] Error 2
make: [all] Error 2

Error B:

/.../path_qp_generated_oases.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/.../path_qp_generated_oases.cpp:320:10: error: invalid use of ‘ACADO::ModelContainer::ModelContainer’
      ocp.ModelContainer.SetNOD(7);

make2: [examples/CMakeFiles/my_examples_path_qp_generated_oases.dir/my_examples/path_qp_generated_oases.cpp.o] Error 1
make1:[examples/CMakeFiles/my_examples_path_qp_generated_oases.dir/all] Error 2
make: all Error 2

I am using the version of acado-master downloaded today:
Branch: master
Commit: 2cde3c748856ca16a4460e05149c1e5de362526f
Remote: acado/acado

Also have the same problem with acado-stable downloaded today:
~/ACADOtoolkit$ git rev-parse HEAD
e0cc4b058e1dc60c4e57f306dc7c7db41a582451

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
There is currently a bug in [ACADO Toolkit](https://acado.github.io) where it sometimes mis-counts or completely ignores the `OnlineData` variables that you use to define your problem.
The method is `setNOD()` with a lower-case "s".

Here's some example code which may help other people...

.

First make sure you install the latest ACADO source from github.

Define your non-linear optimization problem for ACADO like shown in the [documentation](https://acado.github.io/documentation.html):

```
DifferentialState x;
DifferentialState y;

Control u;

DifferentialEquation f;
f << dot(x) == 1.0*u;
f << dot(y) == 2.0*u;

OnlineData d0;
OnlineData d1;
OnlineData d2;

etc.

OCP ocp(0.0, steps*Ts, steps);
ocp.minimizeLSQ(W, h);
ocp.minimizeLSQEndTerm(W, h);
ocp.setModel(f);

ocp.setNOD(3);

OCPexport mpc(ocp);
```

You have to manually count your number of `OnlineData` and put that number into `setNOD()`.

Then compile, generate the code, etc. like described in the documentation.

Now you can search through the code in the export directory to find these `OnlineData` variables that were previously ignored:

```
 grep -R "od\[" *
```

Also note the `test.c` program won't set these variables.

In your own code, you will need to set their value.
If you have 3 `OnlineData`, you set them to be the same for each step along the control horizon like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (N + 1); ++i)
{
  acadoVariables.od[i * NOD + 0] = 1.0;
  acadoVariables.od[i * NOD + 1] = 9.0;
  acadoVariables.od[i * NOD + 2] = 5.0;
}
```

Hope this helps!